# Powershell get overall CPU usage

Tags: powershell, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a script that outputs my overall cpu usage. But if I compare this to the Task Manager, I get a different number. Is my script just wrong or is there a better way to do it?

```
$cpu = Get-WmiObject win32_processor 
logwrite $cpu.LoadPercentage
```

Task Manager says 26% while the output file says 1%. My script says 0%, 1% or 2% most of of the time.

[image: Task Manager says 26% while the output file says 1%]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason being, `CPU Usage` fluctuates with each passing moment, and that is reflected in your task manager. If you see your task manager the `CPU usage` will be fluctuating every time.

`$cpu.LoadPercentage` from your script gives you the `CPU usage` at the `time of creation` of your output file. Hence, you see the anomalies. You should be looking for a more dynamic way of getting `CPU usage` or getting it in intervals.

Comment: The complete Script that I use makes an interval of 1 second between every meassure and is running for almost 2 days. But the Information I get is still always 0%, 2% or 3%. Even when I open multiple windows at the same time, task manager will always say 100% and my script 3% or less.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4c707c1-5e25-4336-9e52-3b924d956737/difference-between-wmi-query-get-loadpercentage-and-taskmanager-cpu-percentage?forum=winserverManagement) link.